# how to import resource file in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have use `QtDesigner` to turn a picture into a `.qrc` file, Then I use `pyrcc5` to turn this `.qrc` file into a `.py` resource:
     `pyrcc5 source.qrc -o  source.py`
then I import this `source.py` file in my  `.py` file. I removed `_rc` so it become like this 
     `import source`
now when I run the `.py` file itself the picture shows up. But when I run it from a `MainPage` the picture does not show. 
This is my main page:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class MainPage(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainPage,self).__init__()
        loadUi('king.ui',self)

app= QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MainPage()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So any solution for this ?

Comment: as provided the issue can be anywhere...

Comment: where is the 'import source' part , in your code ?